# React: custom function parameters

Tags: reactjs

Given a basic component and a custom handleChange() function, where is the parameter of 'id' coming from in App.js?
I know that all event functions receive an event property as an argument, but where did 'id' come from? 
Does this mean that all custom functions I write in a given class based component will receive a parameter besides the event parameter?

**App.js Component**

```
import React from "react"
import TodoItem from "./TodoItem"
import todosData from "./todosData"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            todos: todosData
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(id) {

        console.log("Changed", id)
    }

    render() {
        const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => 
          <TodoItem 
            key={item.id} 
            item={item} 
            handleChange={this.handleChange}
          />)

        return (
            <div className="todo-list">
                {todoItems}
            </div>
        )    
    }
}
```

**TodoItem.js Component**

```
import React from "react"

function TodoItem(props) {
    return (
        <div className="todo-item">
            <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                checked={props.item.completed} 
                onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}
            />
            <p>{props.item.text}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TodoItem
```

**todosData.js**

```
const todosData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "Take out the trash",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: "Grocery shopping",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: "Clean gecko tank",
        completed: false
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: "Mow lawn",
        completed: true
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        text: "Catch up on Arrested Development",
        completed: false
    }
]

export default todosData
```

Comment: *" where is the parameter of 'id' coming from in App.js"* I assume you mean where the value is coming from? You are passing it when you call the function here: `props.handleChange(props.item.id)`. It's a normal function call, there is nothing special about it. *"Does this mean that all custom functions I write in a given class based component will receive a parameter besides the event parameter?"* No, which arguments the function gets passed depends on how the function is called.

Comment: @FelixKling you answered my question in an indirect way. I was just confused on the direction data flows in regard to react components. For example, the top level component (App.js) passes props to all child components like TodoItem.js. I'm still a little confused on how that props.item.id is passed BACK to a parent component. This almost seems like a bi directional data flow.

Comment: The parent component passed a function and data to `TodoItem`. The todo item then calls the function at some point.

Answer (score 0):

> Given a basic component and a custom handleChange() function, where is the parameter of 'id' coming from in App.js?

Here you pass `handleChange` as a prop to the `TodoItem` component:

```
<TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

And here you call it from inside `TodoItem`:

```
onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}
```

> Does this mean that all custom functions I write in a given class based component will receive a parameter besides the event parameter?

Yes, your custom function will receive whatever parameters you pass to it when you call it.